# np.load to a paths file

Tags: python, numpy, path, load

I have a file with all of my pathnames for each .npy file. I have about 5 million files so I would like to avoid unnecessary fors.

What I need to do is to load them all into my data variable like this:

data = np.load( input_file_w_pathnames )

I know this will not work but I was wondering if someone knows of a clever way to do something similar, or at least a way to do this efficiently.

Comment: if all files in the same dic you could open all .csv and store them into `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.load` takes a filename or a file object (a file that you opened).  It uses standard Python file reading tools.  It does not take multiple names or files.

```
np.stack([np.load(f) for f in ['x.npy','x.npy','x.npy']])
```

can join the arrays in each file into a larger array, it is still doing a file by file load.

Keep in mind that `numpy` 'efficiency' is achieved by performing the task in compiled code - it's faster because of the compiling, not because it is getting around the serial nature of the task.  And this task does not come up often enough to warrant special code.

I assume you can easily deal with loading the filenames into a list.

Comment: thank you for the tips.  This seems like the best work around.